# Initialize wide char array

Tags: c++

I have a wide char variable which I want to initialize with a size of string.
I tried following but didn't worked.

```
std::string s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"; //this could be any length 
const int Strl = s.length();
wchar_t wStr[Strl ]; // This throws error message as constant expression expected.
```

what option do i have to achieve this? will malloc work in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is C++, use `new` instead of `malloc`.

It doesn't work because C++ doesn't support VLA's. (variable-length arrays)

The size of the array must be a compile-time constant.

```
 wchar_t* wStr = new wchar_t[Strl];

 //free the memory
 delete[] wStr;
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you *can't* just copy a string to a wide character array - everything is going to go berserk on you.

A `std::string` is built with `char`, a `std::wstring` is built with `wchar_t`. Copying a `string` to a `wchar_t[]` is not going to work - you'll get gibberish back. Read up on UTF8 and UTF16 for more info.

That said, as [Luchian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore) says, [VLAs can't be done in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10546523) and his heap allocation will do the trick.

However, I must ask *why* are you doing this? If you're using `std::string` you shouldn't (almost) ever need to use a character array. I assume you're trying to pass the string to a function that takes a character array/pointer as a parameter - do you know about the `.c_str()` function of a string that will return a pointer to the contents?

Comment: Well, a std::string holds a `char` array. A `wchar_t` is not a `char`, but a wide character. He probably needs to convert a string to a UNICODE representation.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I actually already updated my answer to reflect that. If that's what he's trying to do, manually copying the bytes over is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Well, I hope he's not doing it with memcpy :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Amen to that. However, even in a loop, it'll break on the first hint of a multi-byte char. He really should be using wstring.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi I added the links to Luchians profile and his answer. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::wstring ws;
ws.resize(s.length());
```

this will give you a wchar_t container that will serve the purpose , and be conceptually a variable length container. And try to stay away from C style arrays in C++ as much as possible, the standard containers fit the bill in every circumstance, including interfacing with C api libraries. If you need to convert your string from char to wchar_t , c++11 introduced some string conversion functions to convert from wchar_t to char, but Im not sure if they work the other way around.