# Initialize a wchar_t[] using a string

Tags: c++, string, wmi

Currently, I'm dealing with [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-tasks--computer-software) for collecting the log files from a remote machine.
I have the username of the remote machine initialized as given below.

```
wchar_t pszName[]=L"My username";
```

`pszName[]` is a `wchar_t` array. The trouble I face is that when I pass my username as a parameter of string datatype, I need to initialize `wchar_t` array using a string.

I cannot use a `wchar_t*` pointer because it gives me an error on the later part of the program. I need to initialize something like

```
string username = "My username";
wchar_t pszName[] = .....?.....;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546514/initialize-wide-char-array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t

Comment: Does your `string` contain only ASCII characters or some encoding of Unicode characters?

Comment: Yes sir, my string contains only ASCII characters

Comment: @xskxzr Thank you for the reply. I reffered to the links you have provided But I couldn't find any initialization of a wchat_t[] array. I don't find a difficulty in finding the length of the array. But to initialize the wchar_t[] array using a string is what makes me think. Just like I mentioned in the question, a pointer doesn't suit my requirement.

Comment: Do you have to use `std::string` for username or you can also use `std::wstring`?

Comment: Actually, I'm passing a string from java to c++. The value in the string is to be passed on to a wchar_t[] array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>

std::wstring str_to_wstr(std::string const & str)
{
    int length = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), 0, 0);
    if (!length)
        return L"utf-8 to utf-16 conversion error!";

    std::vector<wchar_t> buffer(length + 1);
    if (!MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, str.c_str(), str.length(), buffer.data(), length))
        return L"utf-8 to utf-16 conversion error!";

    return std::wstring(buffer.data(), length);
}

// ...

std::string username{ "My username" };
std::wstring utf_16_username{ str_to_wstr(username) };

// ... use:
utf_16_username.data();  // wherever you would have used pszName
```

Comment: I would opt to throw an exception instead of return an error string on failure. And on the final return, I would opt to use the `wstring` constructior that takes a length as input, instead of relying on `buffer` being null terminated. The way you are using `MultiByteToWideChar`, it doesn't output a null terminator, you are relying on one being provided by the `vector` constructor. But `MultiByteToWideChar` returns the number of chars written to `buffer`, so no need for `wstring` to count them again.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau "`MultiByteToWideChar` returns the number of chars written to buffer, so no need for wstring to count them again." You are right, no need to count twice.

Comment: You should use hardcoded CP_UTF8 as your error really indicates it expects UTF8 input...

Comment: Now that I take another look, you can just write directly into the allocated wstring. You're making a superfluous copy now. Pre-C++17 (but strictly only after C++110, use `&buffer[0]`, otherwise just pass `buffer.data()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau this looks like copy paste for example [2nd post](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/170009-unicode-string-convertion-help.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your reply seems to be working. But this wasn't what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `std::mbstowcs` [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) to convert your string into `wchar_t*`:

```
std::string username = "My username"; //set your username
wchar_t pszName[] = L"My username";   //initialize pszName with a certain length wide string
std::mbstowcs(pszName, name.c_str(), std::wcslen(pszName)); //copy and convert name from username to pszName
```

And you need to include:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Be aware, that you have to give a maximum length for `pszName`, and that this value actually has to have allocated at least this length in memory! Otherwise you get runtime crashes!

With the current implementation, you can just insert a dummy name of the right length into `pszName` and get the right length with the `std::wcslen` [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen).